# Prevent the any any size class from overriding portrait in storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, autolayout, size-classes

Is there a way on xcode, storyboard to prevent the any any size class from overriding the other size classes?

Answer (score 0):

For my apps I make all of the objects installed only to specific size classes.

What I would try is in the any, any size class select all of the objects, and in the attributes inspector panel to the right, uncheck installed(to all) and add which size classes you need. For example, if you are running your app in portrait mode on the iPhone, you can add the size classes for the iPhone views(compact width and compact, regular).